# A function from [Either a b] to Either [a] [b]

Tags: haskell

Is there a name for the function defined as follows:

```
f :: [Either a b] -> Either [a] [b]
f x = let (y1, y2) = partitionEithers x in
  case y1 of
    [] -> Right y2
    _ -> Left y1
```

Basically if the list contains at least on `Left` it returns all the `Left`s otherwise it returns all the `Right`s.

Alternatively, are there some generalisation of this function over a type class that I've missed?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what are you using this for?

Comment: To return a list of results or alternatively returning a list of errors if there's a failure. There's actually a bunch of parallel tasks I'm performing behind this actually.

Comment: Try one of those https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5BEither%20a%20b%5D%20-%3E%20Either%20%5Ba%5D%20%5Bb%5D

Comment: Shouldn't that be `f :: [Either a b] -> ([[a], [b])`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is (almost) `sequence` for [`Validation`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-5.0.1/docs/Data-Either-Validation.html); you just need to convert your `a`s to `[a]`s. So:

```
traverse (eitherToValidation . first pure)
```

If you rewrite your producer to produce `Validation`s instead of `Either`s in the first place it will be even less noisy.

Answer (score 5):

Well certainly you can get a single Left or the Right using the either monad:

```
Prelude> let a = [Right "hello", Right "World", Right "Bye"]
Prelude> sequence a
Right ["hello","World","Bye"]
Prelude> let a = [Right "hello", Right "World", Left "Bye"]
Prelude> sequence a
Left "Bye"
```

But to get *all* the `Left` values doesn't seem like anything in the base or common libraries I know so you're probably left rolling your own solution.  That said, I think we can find a much more readable solution.  I propose:

```
f x | any isLeft x = lefts x
    | otherwise    = rights x
```

or

```
f x | not (null ls) = ls
    | otherwise     = rs
 where (ls,rs) = partitionEithers x
```